# Unable to test Sandbox Game Center leaderboard on device

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, game-center, gamekit

Here are the things I have set up:

1. Game Center enabled in iTunes Connect (my app version 1.0).
2. Game Center enabled in "Features" section of iTunes Connect.
3. All code in Xcode is established with `GameKit.framework` via `GameCenterManager` subclass, no bugs or deprecated methods.
4. Game Center is turned on in "Capabilities" and present in "Build Phases".
5. Bundle Identifier in `Info.plist` matches the identifier in iTunes Connect.
6. I don't know if I need to but my App ID is only present in iTunes Connect (I don't know how to locate it in Xcode).
7. Sandbox is enabled in Game Center on my device.
8. I cannot, however, see my game in Game Center, so is there something I have to further set up in that regard?
9. I created 3 Sandbox Tester users in iTunes Connect, and currently logged in to Game Center as one of them.
10. I previously logged on to Game Center as my regular Apple ID and tested it out that way, but nothing worked.  However, with the new Sandbox Testers, it appears that I am still building the app from Xcode with my regular Apple ID in "Identity" under the "General" tab.

Given all that, when I press the button that should take me the Game Center, I receive the following message (which I set up):

```
Game Center is Unavailable
Player is not signed in
```

However, I am signed in, and everything seems to be set up ok.  I did not submit my App yet for review...do I need to do that ahead of time before testing Game Center?  That doesn't make sense but, having never worked with `GameKit.framework` before, all possible solutions to this problem make sense.

I am building to iOS 8.3, using Xcode 7.1.2.

Comment: Scratch that, I'm a jackass.  When I was supposed to authenticating the user, I was doing nothing.  I implemented the authentification in a SpriteKit method called `didMoveToView:` which should have been `viewDidAppear:`.  That's why nothing was happening.  My apologies.